# How can I change the background image of the header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background image of my header, the javascript code I'm working with works absolutely fine but when I reload the page, the image gets reset to default.
I want the background-image property to get the new value that I'm assigning from the input.

Here's the code

HTML -

```
<html>

<head>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel=stylesheet href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.css">



    <title>CorpoViz Admin</title>

   <script src="JS/editor.js"></script>



</head>

<body onload=iFrameOn()>
    <div class="jumbotron" id=headerBg>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <h1>Heading</h1>


            <span style="float:right;">
            <input type='file' id='getval' class="inputfile btn btn-default" />
            <label for="getval" class="btn btn-default" style="font-size:20px;">Choose an image</label>
            </span>
```

JavaScript -

```
                document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL, true);
                function readURL(){
                    var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(){
                        document.getElementById('headerBg').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";        
                    }
                    if(file){
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        document.getElementById('headerBg').style.backgroundImage = <?php echo "\"url(\" + reader.result + \")\"; " ?>
                    }
                    document.getElementById('headerBg').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";
                }
```

CSS -

```
     #headerBg{
     background-image:url('');
     background-size:cover;
     background-position: center;
     }
```

Comment: you are calling the readUrl on file change so when you reload the page you need to change the file to change the background

Comment: what result are you expecting to get?

Comment: I want the background image to stay, even after I reload the page@TarasKumpanenko

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage or Cookies to temporarily retain the image url. If you want the changes to be permanent, then store the data inside a database like MySQL.

Example of javascript code to set a local storage item:

```
localStorage.setItem('backgroundUrl', 'http://example.com/test123.png');
```

Example of javascript code to retrieve local storage item:

```
localStorage.getItem('backgroundUrl');
```

## EDIT

If you would like to store the new image url in your database, then you will need a table in mysql dedicated to the header background image.

To update the table check this url:
[PHP mySQLi update table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554673/php-mysqli-update-table)

To retrieve the image URL from the table, check this URL:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: Can you give me the solution with php and mysql?

Comment: @VijitAil just updated, the answer, use google for more understandable examples.